# How can my Drupal module expose custom URLs?

Tags: 7

I'm writing a custom drupal module and have just starter out working with Drupal.

I need to expose a custom URL from my module so that some JavaScript files can request this URL for XML data. How can I do this? I'm not referring to the hook menu. Thanks

Comment: `hook_menu` is the Drupal way to define URL. You can try services Module also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need hook_menu in your .module file.

> This hook enables modules to register paths in order to define how URL requests are handled. Paths may be registered for URL handling only ...

example:

```
function MY_MODULE_menu() {
  $items['path/callback/%/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'my_callback_func',
    'page arguments' => array(2, 3),
  );

  return $items;
}

function my_callback_func($arg2, $arg3) {
  //your process here
  $data = array($arg2, $arg3);
  return drupal_json_output($data);
}
```

in js call this url with 2 arguments: path/callback/VAR_1/VAR_2 - VAR_1 is second argument, VAR_2 is third as defined in "'page arguments' => array(2, 3)" (path is zero argument, callback is first argument)

The $data may be returned in what you want format. In this example this is JSON.

More for hook_menu - http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_menu/7

Comment: Thanks Sveltio, I'll try this. How about XML output? Is there a Drupal function for that?

Comment: try this format_xml_elements($array) - http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/format_xml_elements/7